# PHP ajax returns duplicate from external PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I've looked everywhere for an answer to this one, hopefully someone can help me out. I have the following ajax/JS code, as well as an external PHP file that I call below and then an index.php page to display results.

This code works well with my external php file. It grabs the posted data return from a MySQL database and displays the contents in the #show div. Essentially I am querying a MySql database for host details (ip, mac, etc). This all returns just fine without page refresh. The problem and my question is when I submit the form again with another code the results are again returned BUT appended to the previous results. Question: how do I avoid this?! I have looked into caching and clearing Ajax vars (content) and emptying the PHP page but have had zero luck in getting the previous Ajax call to clear on another submission. Is this a problem with my ajax code? or is there something I need to be clearing on the PHP side of things?

I am relatively new to ajax, generally speaking, but understand how the script works to retrieve information. Is there a way to refresh the external php file to dump the previous post after I scrape the results back to my index.php page?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
              $(function() {
                    $(".submit_button").click(function() {
                        var textcontent = $("#content").val();
                        var dataString = 'content='+ textcontent;
                             $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "HOST_gethost.php",
                            data: dataString,
                            success: function(html){
                            $("#show").after(html);
                            document.getElementById('content').value='';
                });
                }
                return false;
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Thanks ahead of time!!

EDIT more details as I am still having the same issue: after(data) works and html(data) does not. For the life of me, especially after mark explained the two functions, I cannot figure out why one would work and the other not the return for html(data) is just blank, nothing in the debug either.

**JS code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(function() {
                $(".submit_button").click(function() {
                    var textcontent = $("#content").val();
                    var dataString = 'content='+ textcontent;
                         $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "HOST_gethost.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        success: function(data){
                        $("#show").html(data);
                        document.getElementById('content').value='';
            }
            });
            return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

**PHP external file:**

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect('','','') or die (mysql_error);
$db=mysql_select_db('blah', $conn) or die (mysql_error);


$content=$_POST['content'];
$fetch= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blah.blahblah WHERE hostname LIKE     '%$content%'  ");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($fetch);

?>

<div class="showbox"> 
    <table>
        <th>Attributes</th><th>Details</th>
        <tr><td>Name</td><td><?php echo $row['hostname']; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Last Known IP</td><td><?php echo $row['ipv4']; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Last Known User</td><td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>    </tr>
        <tr><td>Last Seen</td><td><?php echo $row['updated']; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Protection</td><td><?php echo $row['encryption_status']; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Firewall</td><td><?php echo $row['firewall_explanation']; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Script Policy</td><td><?php echo $row['policy']; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>GPO Check-in</td><td><?php echo $row['gpo']; ?></td></tr>
</table>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$("#show").html(html);
```

instead of

```
$("#show").after(html);
```

Comment: Whe i change the single line you suggested it breaks the call. When I changed it back to $("#show").after(html); It worked fine again :/

Comment: Try replace this two lines: "success: function(data){
                            $("#show").html(data);"

Comment: Still the same outcome. what is the command that is causing the append?

Comment: If i change both lines to data and keep `after` it works: success: function(data){$("#show").after(data);} After must be the append?

Comment: It works in both cases. "$("#show").after(data)" - add your result after "show" div and when you click again - it add your result after "show" div again (old text remains). When you use "$("#show").html(data)" - it replaces all contents of "show" div with your "data".

Comment: I posted more details to see if we cannot get this to work....it may be something on the catching php side. If I cant get this to work soon, im going to scrap and code in local storage (which im familiar with) :/ ALSO im aware of the security flaws in this- I need to get it to work, before i tweak.

Comment: Try that: add new div after "show" in your html code, name it "show_data" and replace only one string from your initial script: "$("#show_data").html(html);"

Comment: This worked like a charm- not sure why it was rejected the previous attempt at html() BUT it is working now. Thank you so much mark!